# How to use inset box-shadow on select element?

Tags: html, css, html-select

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/UD2QP/) is an example of using box shadow on select tags.

But there used wrapper element, so inset attribute doesn't work there.

Is it possible to use inset box shadow on select tag?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by wrapping the select element with a div. Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/UD2QP/779/.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="select_wrapper">
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="week">11 week</option>
        <option value="month">11 month</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
select,
div.select_wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 430px;
    color:#58595b;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);        
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    resize:none;
}

select {        
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

div.select_wrapper {
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work on `input="text"` but I doubt that it will work on `select`-s

```css
select, input {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;

  display:block;
  margin:20px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="First Name" />

<select name="bar">
  <option value="foobar">Foobar</option>
  <option value="bazbat">Bazbat</option>
</select>
```